# How to have separate routers module in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

How can I decouple this class? I would like to put the paths in another file, is it possible to move the routes in another file?

```py
@api.route('/home', '/api/email')
class Server(Resource):

    def create_server(app, oauth=None):
        if not oauth:
            oauth = default_provider(app)

        app = prepare_app(app)

        @app.before_request
        def load_current_user():
            user = User.query.get(1)
            g.user = user

        @app.route('/home')
        def home():
            return 'home'

        @app.route('/oauth/authorize', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        @oauth.authorize_handler
        def authorize(*args, **kwargs):
            return True
```

Those

```py
@app.route('/home') # and 
@app.route('/oauth/authorize', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

have to be in another file.

My attempt was this, I tried to create a file for routers:

```py
class Router():
    def __init__(self, app, oauth):
        self.app = app
        self.oauth = oauth

    @app.route('/home')
    def home():
        return 'home'
```

I'm getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see a package you can use for flask projects called [**`Flask-Via`** <sup>[pypi]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Via/), inspired by the Django URL configuration system and designed to add similar functionality to Flask applications that have grown beyond a simple single file application. The following example is given from the [docs](https://flask-via.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of this project:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.via import Via
from flask.ext.via.routers.default import Functional

app = Flask(__name__)

def foo(bar=None):
    return 'Foo View!'

routes = [
    Functional('/foo', foo),
    Functional('/foo/<bar>', foo, endpoint='foo2'),
]

via = Via()
via.init_app(app, route_module='flask_via.examples.basic')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I think this is exactly what you want :) and you can move it to another python module for example called `routers.py`.